# Sending email in IIS7.5 (CDO.Message) - apostrophe in email

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, smtp, iis-7.5

We use IIS7.5 and CDO.Message to send emails from a website written in Classic ASP - but when an email address contains an apostrophe, the send fails.
I've tried encoding the apostrophe as &#39; - but this doesn't make an difference.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Is it just that IIS cannot handle apostrophes in emails?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It's probably an issue with your ASP code, and not not an IIS problem. Are you correctly escaping apostrophes by replacing them with a double?

In classic ASP, you have to replace the `'` with `''`.